# xsl disable-output-escaping copy-of

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xsl:template like this:

```
<xsl:template name="box2">
<xsl:param name="txt"/>
  <div class="panel1">
    <xsl:value-of select="$txt" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

then I call templete with param:

```
<xsl:call-template name="box2">
<xsl:with-param name="txt">
    &lt;b&gt;First&lt;/b&gt;
    <b>Second</b>
</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

result is like this:

```
<div class="panel1">
    <b>First</b>
    Second
</div>
```

I tried to use copy-of Instead value-of, then result is:

```
<div class="panel1">
    &lt;b&gt;First&lt;/b&gt;
    <b>Second</b>
</div>
```

is a way to have result like this:

```
<div class="panel1">
    <b>First</b>;
    <b>Second</b>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very difficult to follow without having a context. Please post an example of your XML input, and a **complete** (if minimal) XSLT stylesheet. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you can see my problem in : http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRb/4
i want <b><i>TEXT</i></b> at output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying shows, there is no `disable-output-escaping` allowed on `xsl:copy-of`. If you are using XSLT 1.0 then your parameter is a result tree fragment which you can convert to a node-set and then you can apply templates to the nodes where for text nodes you use `value-of` with `disable-output-escaping` while for element nodes you use `copy-of`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:template name="box2">
  <xsl:param name="rtf"/>
  <div class="panel1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($rtf)/node()" mode="doe"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="doe">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="doe">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="box2">
      <xsl:with-param name="rtf">
      &lt;b&gt;First&lt;/b&gt;
      <b>Second</b>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

See http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rN9 for an example which outputs

```
<div class="panel1">
      <b>First</b>
      <b>Second</b></div>
```

Note that `disable-output-escaping` is not supported in Mozilla browsers as it is an optional serialization feature while Gecko simply renders the XSLT result tree, it does not serialize it.

With XSLT 2.0 it is easier as you don't use `exsl:node-set`, see http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRb which does

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template name="box2">
  <xsl:param name="fragment"/>
  <div class="panel1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$fragment/node()" mode="doe"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="doe">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="doe">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="box2">
      <xsl:with-param name="fragment">
      &lt;b&gt;First&lt;/b&gt;
      <b>Second</b>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

In your comments you have added more complexity to the input you have, if you want to use the same approach then you can't simply take deep copies of element nodes, you need to take a shallow copy and process the child nodes the same way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:for-each select="//root/cmnt">
      <xsl:call-template name="box1">
        <xsl:with-param name="rtf">
          <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </b>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="box1">
    <xsl:param name="rtf"/>
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($rtf)/node()" mode="doe"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="doe">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="doe">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="doe"/>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very much a beginner.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very much a beginner. I'm using .NET and it only support XSLT 1.0, my xsl begin with:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
and has error:
Cannot find the script or external object that implements prefix 'exsl'.

I don't know what can i do.

Comment: .NET has two XSLT processors from Microsoft, `XslCompiledTransform` and `XslTransform`. Which one do you use? My first sample should work as posted with `XslCompiledTransform`.

Comment: at first I used ASP.NET XML Control, but when I used XslCompiledTransform with msxsl:node-set then my output is like :
http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRb/4
but i want <b><i>TEXT</i></b> at output

Comment: Well you are changing the question if you increase the complexity of the input but I have edited the answer to address more complex input.